# jQuery sortable: list elements jump when one element is dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery's sortable to move elements between two lists.

My issue is that the list shifts (all the elements down, then back up) when I drag an element. This seems to happen only when there is text (or another element) inside the sortable element.

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/vrCC7/2/:

- It's smooth to move elements within the second list.
- Elements jump when moved within the first list.
- Moving an element from the second to the first list offsets it strangely.

Code:

```
    <div id = "containment">
    <ul class = "sortable connectedSortable"  >

        <li class = "child">1</li>
        <li class = "child">2</li>
        <li class = "child">3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class = "sortable connectedSortable"  >
        <li class = "child"></li>
        <li class = "child"></li>
        <li class = "child"></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add a

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

in child class seems to do the trick.

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrCC7/7/)

Comment: You're welcome. Another solution would be to add an `&nbsp;` in your li "without text".

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem came from css overflow on list :

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
```